# how to build hyperlink for query string in php

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have a question, How I can add another get variable in my current url

```
 book.php?action=addressbook
```

i want to add

```
 book.php?action=addressbook&page=2
```

how to generate hyperlink for this, i have tried it using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] but query string are not included in url its showing something like that

```
book.php?page=2
```

I want to append my other variables to query string

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [http_build_query();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to append more params to your URL

```
$params = $_GET;
$params["item"] = 45;
$new_query_string = http_build_query($params);
```

for instance:

```
$data = array('page'=> 34,
              'item' => 45);

echo http_build_query($data); //page=34&item=45
or include amp

echo http_build_query($data, '', '&amp;');  //page=34&amp;&item=45
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$get = $_GET;

$get['page'] = 2;

echo '<a href="book.php?<?php echo http_build_query($get); ?>">Page 2</a>';
```